# fill missing places in c++ program to get desired output

Tags: c++

Fill up the blanks with appropriate keyword to get the desired output according to the test cases. (Language use c++)

Sample Test Cases

```
                     input      output
Test Case 1           4           square = 16, ++ square = 25 
test case 2           -8           square =64, ++ square = 49
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

______ int SQUARE(int x) { ______ x * x; }
​
int main() {

    int a , b, c;

    cin >> a ;

    b = SQUARE(a);

    cout << "Square = " << b << ", ";

    c = SQUARE(++a);

   cout << "++ Square = " << c ;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: And did you have a question?

Comment: So, you want people to make your homework?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Second blank place is "return"

First may be "inline" or nothing